# websocket connection closed before established laravel on ubuntu server?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, websocket, laravel-websockets

I have implemented websocket in laravel framework. It is working fine on localhost windows OS but giving error on live ubuntu server

```
["Connecting",{"transport":"ws","url":"ws://IP-Address:6001/app/qwerty?protocol=7&client=js&version=7.0.0&flash=false"}]
```

I think this is error because port is not allowing to connect. but i am not sure about it. What should i do? I am using aws webservices

Added rule
[image]

Comment: If you SSH to the AWS instance you are hosting this can you connect to the websocket via the SSH terminal?

Comment: You can try to configure the security group rules to allow incoming connections to that port from outside. If you're hosting this on EC2 then you can go to the EC2 web interface and add an inbound rule to the security group attached to your instance

Comment: i tried but i really dont understand what i need to do there

Comment: When you're editing the security group there's two tabs: Inbound and Outbound rules. In the Inbound rules add a rule for TCP connections to allow all connections to port 6001 from any IP (I think you can specify any IP as 0.0.0.0) . There's more info [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/working-with-security-groups.html#adding-security-group-rule)

Comment: ok let me try again

Comment: I added rule.. check screen shot at top

Comment: I would suggest not using "All TCP" but just TCP with the specific port you want to open up to traffic

Comment: That Problem is solved but new problem is arises.Now getting this error 
```
Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

```